# Azure Data Factory - how do I convert a string HH:mm to Time(7) type in Azure SQL?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Times are generated in the format of HH:mm in source CSV files. But when it needs to go through data flow to be copied in a Time(7) column in the sink Azure SQL, it always turns up with NULL value.

I have tried to concat :00.000000 at the end but does not work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by adding a column pattern in "Derived Column": $$ --> concat('1900-01-01 ', $$, ':00')